# Enlarge integer tag value in xpath

Tags: xml, web-services, xpath, web, soapui

Could someone please recommend a solution for the following problem.

I have such xml:

```
<nuts1:SettlementRequest>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <nuts1:MeterReadingId>1842869</nuts1:MeterReadingId>
```

I need to take MeterReadingId field, add to it 1 and input this value into the next request which should look like:

```
</nuts:Header>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <nuts1:MeterReadingId>1842870</nuts1:MeterReadingId>
```

first I used such code:

```
//*:SettlementRequest/*:MeterReadingId/text()+ 1
```

But SOAPUI returns the value like

```
MeterReadingId  [1.84287E6]
```

That is why I wrote complicated xpath:

```
concat(substring-before(string(//*:SettlementRequest/*:MeterReadingId/text()+ 1), '.'), substring-before(substring-after(string(//*:SettlementRequest/*:MeterReadingId/text()+ 1), '.'), 'E'))
```

This piece of code works till you need to increment the Id which ends like ...69 so the final value should be 1842870. This code makes the following:

```
MeterReadingId  [184287]
```

It just omits the last 0...So I can not get the correct value.
Could someone provide any ideas of how to add 1 to current meterReadingId so that I could receive 1842870.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that SOAPUI returns this format for numbers even if you use XPath functions as [`ceiling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/ceiling) which evaluates a decimal number and returns the smallest integer.

So I recommend the follow approach;

Supposing that your first testStep is named `SOAP Request 1` and the request as you show contains:

```
<nuts1:SettlementRequest>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <nuts1:MeterReadingId>1842869</nuts1:MeterReadingId>
...
```

And in the second testStep where you want to use the previous `<MeterReadingId>` plus 1 use the follow notation:

```
</nuts:Header>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <nuts1:MeterReadingId>${=${SOAP Request#response#//*:SettlementRequest/*:MeterReadingId/text()} + 1}</nuts1:MeterReadingId>
...
```

Explanation for `${=${SOAP Request 1#response#//*:SettlementRequest/*:MeterReadingId/text()} + 1}`:

Of the previous expression first SOAPUI evaluates `${SOAP Request 1#response#//*:SettlementRequest/*:MeterReadingId/text()}` which takes the testStep request by its name (in this case `SOAP Request`, gets the `response` property and applies the XPath so it evaluates to `1842869`, so now  after this process it have `${=1842869+1}`.

Then SOAPUI evaluates the expression inside `${=}` as groovy script, so it returns the `1842869+1` sum and applies toString() to the result giving you the expected output which is `1842870`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: @AlyonaKovalyova nice to help you `:)`